# disable progress bar animation in Qt

Tags: windows, qt, progress-bar, pyqt4

Is it possible to disable animation of the progress bar in Qt and make it behave like a meter instead?

Below is the default behavior, and I would instead like it to not have the shiny wave go through it periodically. I was hoping to use it to show used resources such as CPU, memory, and disk space.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

css for use in qt designer:

```
 QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: #3add36;
     width: 1px;
 }

 QProgressBar {
     border: 2px solid grey;
     border-radius: 0px;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

pyqt example:

```
my_progress_bar = QProgressBar()
my_progress_bar.setStyleSheet(" QProgressBar { border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center; } QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: #3add36; width: 1px;}")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that is ugly. Is there a more native-looking approach?

Comment: I found ```"""

         QProgressBar::chunk {
         background-color: rgb(0, 179, 0);
         width: 1px;
            }

         QProgressBar {
             border: 1px solid #acacac;
             border-radius: 0px;
             text-align: center;
            background: #dfdfdf;

         }
        """``` a little more native-looking though not perfect

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the progress bar you are using is the [Windows Vista look](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qprogressbar.html). You should be able to modify the behavior by changing the [stylesheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html). Try replacing the background, image of the progressbar and/or the chunk.