# How to disable the progression animation of a QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QProgressBar showing the progress of an ongoing algorithm. It works just fine in a normal utilization.

But I also have a STOP button allowing user to stop the algo, for example at 42%. At this point, I set the value of the QProgressBar at 42.

The problem is, the progress bar has an animation (like a white ray moving from left to right) showing progress.
I would like to keep this animation when the algorithm is still running, but stop it when user press the Stop button.

I could set the value to 0 or max when the button stop is pressed, but we still want to keep the value when user pressed stop (42% in my example).

It is similar to this question which was not really answered : [disable progress bar animation in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556482/disable-progress-bar-animation-in-qt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable progress bar animation in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556482/disable-progress-bar-animation-in-qt)

Comment: No, as I mentioned it in the last line of my question.
Also, I don't want to modify the style, as I want to use the default style (for windows10 for example). I just want to be able to disable and re-enable the animation...

Comment: Well, it is actually the only way you have : playing with stylesheets, as it is the origin of the light ray.
If you want to have it when it is running and not when it is not, simply use the default stylesheet when you start the algorithm (get it using `styleSheet` from `Qwidget`), and the second one you made yourself when you call the function that stops it.
Saving the `QStyle` may be better, but I am not too sure.

Comment: Is there a way to get the default stylesheet, and modify it only to disable the animation ?

Comment: Comment above edited. For you convenience :
Yes. `styleSheet()` from `QWidget`. But you may want to save its `QStyle` instead, although it may not be performance-friendly.
A stylesheet can be set at any moment as a `QString` via `setStyleSheet(QString)` again from `QWidget`

Comment: I'll look in it ...

Comment: The styleSheet is empty, and Ireally don't know what to add in it.

Comment: Maybe you could try another signalisation for when you stop your algorithm ?
For example, changing its colour (like on Windows) ?

Comment: I could use an alternative way, or set a definitive stylesheet. But I would like to know (maybe just for the sake of knowing) if it is possible to keep the default style and just modify something so the animation would stop (and restart). So for example if we build the app for a different platform like linux kde, the progress bar would have a linux kde style, not the style I would have fixed (which would feel windowsish)...